# How do you animate multi text in, stay for a few seconds and animate out using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, html5-canvas

*** Update ****
Manage to get all 3 line of text to move out together but trying to resolve the issue of after moving out the text will appear again. Updated the codes below.

*** Update 2 ****
Ok, I managed to solve the issue (I think). I just need to add animation-fill-mode: forwards; for the main div and added animation-fill-mode: backwards for all the inner content. But I'm open if any expert have a better solutions.

I've been trying to learn animation and I want to this type of animation, preferably with just using CSS but if that is not possible I don't mind CSS and JS.

What I want to do is this:, I have 3 line of text

XXXXXXXXXX

xxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxx

When the page load, the first line will appear follow by the second and the third. Than they will stay for say 5 seconds before all 3 move out and fade off.

So far I've managed to do this: [View in Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQQEpK)

```css
.heading-primary {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  animation: moveOutRight 2s ease-out 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}
.heading-primary--main {
  display: block;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3.5rem;
  animation-name: moveInLeft;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards; 
}
.heading-primary--sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  animation: moveInLeft 2s ease-out 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: backwards; 
}
.heading-primary--sub1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  animation: moveInLeft 2s ease-out 2s;
      animation-fill-mode: backwards; 

}

@keyframes moveInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-10rem);
  }
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveOutRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(10rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header__text-box">
            <h1 class="heading-primary"><span class="heading-primary--main">Outdoors </span><span class="heading-primary--sub">is where life happens</span>
              <span class="heading-primary--sub1">is where life happens</span>
  </h1></div>
```

But how do I make the 3 text move out together rather than one at a time. ie I want them to come in one at a time which is working but can't find a way to make them move out together. I think it has something to do with the delay timing which I've set which affect the moving out too.

Comment: in html just all the span class is taken as heading-primary--main

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I manage to put another moveOutRight under heading-primary div and set the animation delay. But after the move out the text will show up again.

Comment: I did not got your point

Comment: What I was asking is how after moving in the 3 line of text individually, I can than move it out all at once. You said heading-primary--main which I'm not sure what you mean but it did give me the idea of separating the keyframe animation and set the moveOutRight function on the main div which is heading-primary.

Comment: ok just change the animation time like animation-duration: 10s